# Why am I unable to delete an album in the 'My Music' folder?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm new to this and got Windows 7 the other day.

What I am wanting to do is simply delete an album from the 'My Music' folder but I can't seem to be able to do this - if I right click, there is no delete option.

Comment: Did you try shift-delete on your keyboard?

Comment: Yep tried that - I can't even move a file from one folder to another even by dragging it.

Comment: I need to be an administrator. Looking at the settings, I'm an owner so I cannot even add a new folder to 'my music'

Answer (score 1):

I will start answering in the comment section. I found the answer: It wasn't to do with permissions, it was the way I accessed the 'my music' folder - from the start menu, I could only 'view' the music folder but if I go through my documents and user to 'my music' I can then have full control so I just changed the path to point to that version from the start menu